# Android редактирование .doc или .pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf, поиск-библиотек, doc

Необходимо имея шаблон документа, заполнить поля в нем, и сохранить после. Все это сделать программно, изнутри Android приложения. Есть два варианта:

1. Есть .pdf файл. Заполнить поля в нем и сохранить его
2. Есть .doc файл. Заполнить поля в нем, преобразовать его в .pdf и сохранить.

Проблема в том что нельзя использовать коммерческие библиотеки, и библиотеки с лицензиями, которые требуют открытия исходного кода.
Большинство ответов, что я находил, были достаточно древние, думаю за это время вышли новые библиотеки. Или библиотеки которые в них советовались, не имеют документации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для создания и редактирования .pdf документов можно использовать библиотеку iText(ссылка: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/downloads). Некоторые библиотеки(к примеру iText 7 Core) имеют коммерческую лицензию. Но pdfHTML имеет открытый исходный код и абсолютно бесплатна.pdfHTML позволяет конвертировать HTML-код в .pdf файл. Также могу посоветовать библиотеку PDFBox (https://pdfbox.apache.org).